# I want to drop all the "dots" in my python dataframe

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnyUv.png)I have a data frame with missing values. I applied df.dropna() to remove the Nan but the dots entered as missing values were not removed. How can I remove these dots from my data frame? see picture below

Thanks[enter image description here][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnyUv.png)

Comment: Try `df.replace()`

Comment: df.Deaths = df.Deaths.astype(str)
df.Deaths = df.Deaths.str.replace('.', '')                                                                     
                                                                                                                                 #This code only removed the dots from Deaths column alone. I need a code that will remove all the dots in all the columns. thanks

Comment: @Beta please expantiate more on this am new in python programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following:

```py
import numpy as np

df.replace('.', np.nan)
```

This will replace values exactly matching the string `'.'` but leave other strings which contain a `.` next to other characters untouched.

Then you can use `df.dropna()` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways you could do this:

**Specific columns:**

If the `.` characters are only in specific columns such as `Deaths, Death Rate, Age Adjusted Death Rate`, you can do this:

```py
df2 = df[ (df['Deaths'] != '.') & (df['Death Rate'] != '.') & (df['Age Adjusted Death Rate'] != '.') ]
```

**All columns:**

If the `.` characters can be in any column in the dataframe, you can do this:

```py
df3 = df.replace('.', np.nan).dropna()
```

Input:

```
   Year     Leading Cause Sex        Race Ethnicity Deaths Death Rate Age Adjusted Death Rate
0  2011         Influenza   F              Hispanic      .          .                       .
1  2012           Assault   F    White Non-Hispanic      1       15.5                    13.5
2  2013  All Other Causes   F    Not Stated/Unknown      .          .                       .
3  2014                 X   F  Other Race/Ethnicity      1          .                       .
4  2015                 Y   F              Hispanic      1       16.6                    18.6
5  2016         Influenza   M              Hispanic      .          .                       .
6  2017           Assault   M    White Non-Hispanic      1       15.5                    13.5
7  2018  All Other Causes   M    Not Stated/Unknown      .          .                       .
8  2019                 X   M  Other Race/Ethnicity      1          .                       .
9  2020                 Y   M              Hispanic      1       16.6                    18.6
```

Output:

```
df2:
   Year Leading Cause Sex      Race Ethnicity Deaths Death Rate Age Adjusted Death Rate
1  2012       Assault   F  White Non-Hispanic      1       15.5                    13.5
4  2015             Y   F            Hispanic      1       16.6                    18.6
6  2017       Assault   M  White Non-Hispanic      1       15.5                    13.5
9  2020             Y   M            Hispanic      1       16.6                    18.6

df3:
   Year Leading Cause Sex      Race Ethnicity  Deaths  Death Rate  Age Adjusted Death Rate
1  2012       Assault   F  White Non-Hispanic     1.0        15.5                     13.5
4  2015             Y   F            Hispanic     1.0        16.6                     18.6
6  2017       Assault   M  White Non-Hispanic     1.0        15.5                     13.5
9  2020             Y   M            Hispanic     1.0        16.6                     18.6
```